# How to save stream of image data to the root of the local app data folder in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am trying to save the stream of image data to a file. I was able to save it to Pictures library though.
But I want to save it to a  file in the root of my application/ project.
I was trying the below but it doesn't work.

```
         using (MediaLibrary mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary())
         mediaLibrary.SavePicture(@"\DefaultScreen.jpg", stream);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should use **LocalStorage**.
Here is a simple solution to do this:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
  if (!isoStore.FileExists(fileName)
  {
    var sr = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(fileName, UriKind.Relative));

    using (var br = new BinaryReader(sr.Stream))
    {
      byte[] data = br.ReadBytes((int)sr.Stream.Length);
      string strBaseDir = string.Empty;
      const string DelimStr = "/";
      char[] delimiter = DelimStr.ToCharArray();
      string[] dirsPath = fileName.Split(delimiter);

      // Recreate the directory structure
      for (int i = 0; i < dirsPath.Length - 1; i++)
      {
          strBaseDir = Path.Combine(strBaseDir, dirsPath[i]);
          isoStore.CreateDirectory(strBaseDir);
      }

      using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(isoStore.CreateFile(fileName)))
      {
          bw.Write(data);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here you can find all info about data in Windows Phone:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: We can't store it to application/project root directory ? I already have one image there .I was trying atleast if I can overwrite.And if I want to refer it again later what is the path I have to use ?

Comment: Here you can find all info about data in winodws phone http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541(v=vs.105).aspx