# Screenshot in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Can anyone please tell me how to take screenshot and save it to the folder programmatically in windows phone 7.I don't want to save images in the MediaLibrary(),but i want to save it into the folder which is  in the root directory of the application

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you to take screenshot against an AppBar button click action. However you have to modify the code to save screenshot into root folder of the Application. The following links will help you.

[Save into local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15221923/how-to-save-stream-of-image-data-to-the-root-of-the-local-app-data-folder-in-win)
[Data for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

```
private void ApplicationBarScreenshotButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var fileName = String.Format("MyImage_{0:}.jpg", DateTime.Now.Ticks);
            WriteableBitmap bmpCurrentScreenImage = new WriteableBitmap((int)this.ActualWidth, (int)this.ActualHeight);
            bmpCurrentScreenImage.Render(LayoutRoot, new MatrixTransform());
            bmpCurrentScreenImage.Invalidate();
            SaveToMediaLibrary(bmpCurrentScreenImage, fileName, 100);
            MessageBox.Show("Captured image " + fileName + " Saved Sucessfully", "WP Capture Screen", MessageBoxButton.OK);

            currentFileName = fileName;
        }

        public void SaveToMediaLibrary(WriteableBitmap bitmap, string name, int quality)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Save the picture to the Windows Phone media library.
                bitmap.SaveJpeg(stream, bitmap.PixelWidth, bitmap.PixelHeight, 0, quality);
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                // Use Above link to store file into Root folder.
                //new MediaLibrary().SavePicture(name, stream);
            }
        }
```